# Spread operator syntax error with node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

I've read a lot of previous answers and nothing has worked. When attempting to run my server with 'node server.js' it throws a syntax error on a spread operator that exists within one of my node module files (that I can not change)

Error:

```
/node_modules/package/index.js 
   app.requestDefaults = requestPromise.defaults({ ...authOptions, json:true}); 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10) 
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10) 
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
```

I've added the following to my babelrc which has not fixed the issue:

```
  "plugins": [["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }]]
```

Any other options as to why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps you could you show us the code and the error too?

Comment: I think its the node version, only the latest versions support it. what is the node version?

Comment: @phuzi have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when I was updating node from 6.* to 12.* it wasn't working properly, after downloading nvm and using that to force node to a later version this error no longer appears.